# didReceiveRemoteNotification is not triggering when app is in background in iOS12 & Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, swift4

```
func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
    fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    //Setting my code here according to requirement

}
```

Comment: Please update your question with a push notification payload